# Effect of Simulation Error on the Monte Carlo Estimator

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, asymptotics, error-propagation

Given a random variable $X$ with known pdf $f$ and some computer simulation model $g(x): \mathcal  
 R \rightarrow \mathcal R$, mapping samples $x \sim f$ to a scalar metric $g$, we can estimate the probability $P(g(x) > 0)$ using Direct Monte Carlo Simulation:

$\hat{p} = 1/N \sum_{i=1}^N I(x_i)$, where the indicator function $I(x)$ is $1$ if $g(x)>0$ and $0$ otherwise.

The variance of this estimator is:

${\rm var}[\hat{p}] = \frac{p(1-p)}{N}$, which we estimate to be ${\hat{\rm{var}}}[\hat{p}] = \frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{N}$.

Now suppose that we do not always observe the outcome of $I$ correctly, i.e., we occasionally record $I=1$ although in reality $g(x) < 0$. This might for instance be the result of using some approximation $\hat g$ in place of $g$.

Assuming that the error between $g(x_i)$ and $\hat g(x_i)$ is normally distributed for all samples $x_i \sim f$ with known mean and variance, is there a way to "propagate" the uncertainty stemming from $\hat g$ to the estimated variance of our estimator ${\hat{\rm{var}}}[\hat{p}]$.

Comment: If there is a recording error in $I(x_i)$, the reported value remains a Bernoulli rv with a different probability $q$, meaning that the variance is then $q(1-q)/N$.

Comment: Thank you @Xi'an for spotting the mistake in my question!

Comment: @Xi'an, could we adapt our estimate of the variance based on the knowledge about the error?

Comment: $q=P(\hat g(X)>0)$ requires the distributions of $X$ as well as $\hat g$.

Comment: @Xi'an the distributions of both $X$ and $\hat g$ are known. I am wondering if (and how) I can make use of this information to account for the error in the estimation.